# Runtime Error '424'- Object Required

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub BrowseToSite()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    'Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "www.bigbasket.com"

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        DoEvents
    Loop


    Debug.Print IE.LocationName; IE.LocationURL
    IE.Document.forms("input").elements("text").Value = "tomato"
    IE.Document.forms("input").elements("go").Click


End Sub
```

While running it is showing

> run time error 424-Object Required.

What to do ?

Comment: Make sure you have enabled from references : Microsoft Internet Controls

Answer (score 0):

You're using early binding so you need to make sure you have the appropriate reference.

Just as important, you've commented out the SET line.

To fix:
Remove the apostrophe and test. If you get the same error then check your references.  If your still get the error then come back and tell us specifically where.  That error should highlight the offending row.

Comment: Since he is using the "declare and allocate" syntax with `Dim ... as New ...`, he does not need the `Set ...` line.

Comment: well now i feel a certain kind of special. I've been using set in conjunction with dim as new.   now this seems to beg the question, why is the line written and then commented out?  could it be that attempting to set the object raised an error and removing the line caused the error manifest itself differently, for example, in the event if a missing reference?  in any event, feel free to call me by my name.  the shoe fits me well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .. I couldn't deal with the search button well although it didn't throw an error but it seems that the search button doesn't work

```
Sub BrowseToSite()
Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "www.bigbasket.com"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Debug.Print ie.LocationName; ie.LocationURL
ie.document.all.Item("input").Value = "tomato"
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("input-group-btn")(0).getElementsByTagName("button")(0).Click
End Sub
```